# XMonad Shortcut and Zenity/Qt

Tags: bash, qt, xmonad, zenity

Hey guys I want to set a new shortcut for my small costum script (its not optimal, but it works), Qt scripts also dont work.
For that i thought to just add a new line in my xmonad.hs file and it should work, but instead nothing happens when I press the keyboard shortcut and im not really sure why..

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
tablet=$(xsetwacom --list devices)

tablet=$(echo $tablet | grep -oP "stylus id: [0-9][0-9]")
tablet=$(echo $tablet | grep -oP "[0-9][0-9]")

monitors=$(xrandr --listactivemonitors)
#read screen
screen=$(zenity --entry --text "$monitors")

if [[ ${screen} ]]
    then 
        xsetwacom --set "$tablet" MapToOutput HEAD-$screen;
        echo Tablet set to HEAD-$screen;
fi
```

and thats what i changed in the xmonad.hs file (the script is called "tablet" btw):

[xmonad.hs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHn2c.png)

I hope you can help ^^

Comment: Zenity ask for input. You fail to make mention of that here, let alone what input you gave.

Comment: When I start the script from the terminal everything works fine, so I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: If you mean the input I'm giving after I pressed the shortcut, the prompt don't even appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer in the .xsession-errors file..
I have to give the full path. So in my example it was spawn "/home/flo/scripts/tablet"